# Use Reverse Proxy rewrite rule to fetch content from site accessible through HTTP proxy

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr

A client of mine is trying to use an IIS Application Request Routing rule to reverse proxy the contents of another site (controlled by the same client). So far, no issues.

But, from the IIS server the other site is only available through a standard HTTP proxy. It looks like ARR totally ignores the System and .NET Proxy settings.

- We tried setting the default proxy in the web.config, that is ignored.
- We tried setting the system proxy through `netsh winhttp set proxy`.
- We changed the settings in the Internet Explorer connection settings.

All to no avail.

I can't find any documentation on whether ARR supports reverse proxy rules through another proxy. I can imagine this is not supported.

Comment: have you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing) or [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/08/03/application-request-routing-part-2reverse-proxy-and-troubleshooting-arr-urlrewrite-issues/) ?

Comment: @vardius: yes of course. Setting up the reverse proxy itself. Is easy. Having it perform outbound traffic over a http proxy is something that's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP request over an HTTP proxy is actually making the same request to the proxy using the absolute url instead of relative in after the method name.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
```

would be

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
```

Of course the request needs to be made to the proxy server.

You could try achieving this changing rewrite rule. I can't provide an example since I don't have access to a Windows server but you can try to get some guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Setting_Server_Variables).